# Leaflet js map out of bound on small screens

Tags: leaflet, javascript

### What I have

I have a page with leaflet map whose script is:

```js
<script>

    var coords = [
    ["View", 1.23 , 2.34 ],
    ["View", -23.56558 , -46.651428 ],
    ["View", 1.23 , 2.34 ],
    ["View", 1.23 , 2.34 ],
    ["View", -22.9041 , -47.06386 ],
    ["View", -23.587416 , -46.657635 ],];
        
        var map = L.map('map', {
            attributionControl: false,
        })

        L.tileLayer(
            'https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
            maxZoom: 18,
            }).addTo(map);
           
        var customOptions =
            {
            'className' : 'rounded-md border border-primary xl:w-72 lg:w-80 sm:w-72',
            }

        for (var i = 0; i < coords.length; i++) {
            marker = new L.marker([coords[i][1],coords[i][2]])
                .bindPopup(coords[i][0], customOptions)
                .addTo(map);
        }
        const _bounds = coords.map(entry => [entry[1],entry[2]])
        map.fitBounds(_bounds)

</script>
```

Also in order to handle resizing of map on small screens, I have this just before the HTML `<body>` tag:

```js
<script>
setInterval(function () {
    map.invalidateSize();
  }, 100);
</script>
```

### Problem

On big screens, the map is within the bounds. On small screens, the map goes out of bound and shows the whole world.

### How to reproduce this error ?

1. Visit this [link](https://stirring-kangaroo-f803ee.netlify.app/en/chile/) on a big screen device - note how the map looks like - it is bounded
2. Now visit the same link in a small device (resolution <=360px)
3. Try to see the map by clicking on 'Show map'
4. If you are able to see that the map is still bounded, just refresh the page - the map goes unbounded - it shows the whole world

Comment: You have just changed the source on https://stirring-kangaroo-f803ee.netlify.app/en/chile/. Is question still valid?

Comment: What do you mean by changed source ?

Comment: This code `setInterval(function () { map.invalidateSize();}, 100);` dissapeared and it's no longer possible to reproduce behavior described above.